# How to call a Controller method which is accepting two models?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

It seems perfectly valid if we have a API controller with a method like below:

```
[HttpPost] 
public IHttpActionResult DoStuff([FromBody]ModelA modelA, [FromBody]ModelB modelB)
```

Note the two `[FromBody]` attribute.

The question is, how to call such a method ?

```
localhost/test/DoStuff/
```

POST Data:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ModelA>
 ...
</ModelA>
<ModelB>
 ...
</ModelB>
```

does not seem to be recognized. Any ideas why ?

EDIT: The error data is like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Error>
  <Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
  <ExceptionMessage>Can't bind multiple parameters ('model1' and 'model2') to the request's content.
  </ExceptionMessage>
</Error>
```

Comment: `FromBodyAttribute` can be used only once in the method parameter list.

Comment: Why are you using XML when it make payload heavy?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would say that instead of justifying this *lack of support of multiple models* with documentation, you should find an argument in terms of software architecture perspective: ASP.NET Web API is built on top of *MVC* paradigm, where a view is bound to a model and handled by a controller.

In other words: 1 Model, 1 View, 1 Controller.

Your use case shouldn't be solved with 2 models, but using a *DTO*. Instead of binding 2 parameter to 2 models, design a DTO which includes both models as associations of the whole DTO:

```
// You don't need [FromBody] since complex types are already taken
// from the request body
public IHttpActionResult DoStuff(SomeDto dto)
```

Answer (score 4):

Create a ViewModel which consists of two models and use it as a single Model in your controller.

```
public class MergedModel
{
    public ModelA A{get; set;}
    public ModelB B{get; set;}
}
```

Comment: And renaming the class to MergedModelDto ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can't. The default parameter binding uses the entire body when using the attribute `FromBody`, not just a part of it. So only one `FromBody` will work.

To fix this you can:

- [create your own parameter binding](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) that reads the body and splits it in two models;
- pass in one wrapper model.

Comment: I'm still pretty new to this and I was trying to do the same thing as the OP.  Is it possible to just pass in both of the models and have a delimiter of some sort to separate them in the request body?

Answer (score 2):

You could use stringify for JSON data.

```
 JSON.stringify({ ModelA: o, ModelB: a}),
```

Why are you using XML when it make payload heavy?

Comment: This should be a comment